# Rails: editing the params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am trying to figure out how to edit the params hash in the controller after it's been passed. My hash is set up like this:

```
 def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_type_id)
 end
```

I have this method for editing the hash

```
def alter_user_params_when_not_admin(user_params)
   if(@logged_in_user)
     if(!@logged_in_user.is_admin)
       user_params[:user][:user_type_id] = 1
     end
   else
     user_params[:user][:user_type_id]=1
   end
   user_params
 end
```

I call this method like this:

```
def update
   new_user_params = alter_user_params_when_not_admin(user_params)
   respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(new_user_params)
```

But on the fourth line of the `alter_user_params...` method I get this error:

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Hi @Erik, could you please try my answer and let me know if that fixes your issue? Let me know if not! I will update my answer seeing your output.

Answer (score 1):

`user_params` gives you same what `params[:user]` gives but with strong parameters filtration. So, when you use `user_params`, you don't need to pass `[:user]`, just call `user_params[:user_type_id]` directly.

I suggest the following code:

```
def alter_user_params_when_not_admin(user_params)
  if(@logged_in_user)
    if(!@logged_in_user.is_admin)
      params[:user][:user_type_id] = 1
    end
  else
    params[:user][:user_type_id] = 1
  end

  user_params
end
```

UPDATE:

We don't need to pass and return `user_params` in your custom method:

```
def alter_user_params_when_not_admin
  if(@logged_in_user)
    if(!@logged_in_user.is_admin)
      params[:user][:user_type_id] = 1
    end
  else
    params[:user][:user_type_id] = 1
  end
end
```

And:

```
def update
  alter_user_params_when_not_admin
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of that error is:

```
`user_params[:user]` is `nil` there!
```

`permit` returns a new hash with the keys in it, so you have to save a reference to the hash that `user_params` returns and then modify that.

This should work:

```
def alter_user_params_when_not_admin(user_params)
   #getting the current user_params in another hash
   modified_user_params = user_params

   if(@logged_in_user)
     if(!@logged_in_user.is_admin) 
       #modify the hash      
       modified_user_params[:user_type_id] = 1
     end
   else
     #modify the hash
     modified_user_params[:user_type_id] = 1
   end
   #return the modified user_params hash
   modified_user_params
end
```